# What DNS requirements do I need to map one domain to another?

Tags: dns

I have my first site at `http://www.example.com/members/quiz.php?qid=My-quiz` which queries a database.

I would like to display the exact content for each quiz under my second site: `http://www.mysecondsite.example/quiz.php?qid=My-quiz`

I am new to DNS so I know this is probably a simple question. What do I need to do on both domains to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve this issue solely with DNS. With DNS all you can say that the IP address for `www.example.com` is the same as that for `www.mysecondsite.example`.

Your webserver has to understand that any requests for `www.mysecondsite.example` are actually the same as that for `www.example.com` and has to fulfil or redirect those requests appropriately. Depending on your webserver, search the manual for the topic on redirecting/forwarding requests.